# Can I install Linux from an external hard drive same as flash drive?

Tags: linux, installation

Will instructions to install Linux from a flash drive also work for an external hard drive, or do I need special instructions for that?

Answer (score 2):

It will work, and you can use standard instructions as you would with a regular flash drive.

Just note that you will have to format your entire hard drive and will lose any data that is currently on it.